# Does the KeyPairGenerator class behave differently in Java 1.6 and Java 1.8?

Tags: encryption, java-8, public-key-encryption, java-6, secure-random

I am trying to update an old Java class that generates a signature. It uses the DSA ecnryption algorithm of KeyPairGenerator and a custom seed from SecureRandom class.

```
KeyPairGenerator generator;
generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
byte[] seed = { '1', '2', '3'}; // custom seed
SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
secureRandom.setSeed(seed);
generator .initialize(1024, secureRandom);
KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
```

The issue is that it generates different signatures in the end, depending if I compile it with Java 6 or Java 8. Currently only Java 6 is working and accepted by the server.

My question is, does anyone have any more information if the behavior of one of these classes changed from version updates? Is there a way I can make this class generate the same keypairs in Java 8, as it is doing in Java 6?

Comment: The problem may rather be `SecureRandom` or `SHA1PRNG`, see also specifically for Java 1.6 and 1.8 [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50209640/9014097), where the OP reports different values for both versions. This is the reason why `SecureRandom` should not be used for deriving keys, but a KDF, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118857/9014097).

Comment: I have a vague memory of this misuse of `SecureRandom` being a problem many years ago, but mainly for key generation, as in your code example. But after your code example you mention *The issue is that it generates different signatures in the end* and that implies that you are trying to achieve deterministic DSA signatures. There is a right way to do that and a very wrong way to do it, and the wording here suggests you're doing it the very wrong way. Doing so can result in an easy recovery of the private key.

Comment: Aha, well yes, the code that has been implemented here is actually trying to achieve deterministic DSA signatures. So, for now making this work in 1.8 would be sufficient until the whole logic is implemented again.
After some more testing under Java6/Java8, I saw that SecureRandom returns same value if I call nextBytes() or nextDouble(), but the difference happens in KeyPair class after calling generateKeyPair().
So, does this finding make any difference actually? Or there is still no way to make this generated signature be accepted in 1.8 too.

Comment: I've been indicating that expecting to generate the same key pair using a seed or deterministic stream of bits from a PRNG is a big problem in practice on the [crypto.se] site. I was mainly targeting RSA there, but the same idea goes for DSA and - to a lesser extend - for ECDSA. There are multiple ways to use the random bits and turn them into key pairs, and there is no obligation for an implementation to strictly use one. Best thing may be to get to the source code, implement your own provider with a key pair generator and use that to generate the key pairs. That way the algo remains stable.